# C# - How to add WebP support to GeckoFX embedded browser in Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, geckofx, webp

**I'm building a browser in a C# .NET Windows Form Application and want to add support for WebP (.webp) images.** How would I go about doing this?

**The project uses Geckofx60.64 to create an embedded GeckoFx web browser.** I have not been able to find any information online about adding WebP support to a *web browser* rather than just creating an img2webp conversion system.

**It would be preferable to complete this task from a NuGet package rather than an online install, if possible.**

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=webp indicates that you'd have to be up to Firefox 65 to get webp support, but GeckoFX 60 is only going to have Firefox 60.

Comment: @JohnHatton Thanks for your feedback, is there any way I could manually add support for it using a [Google WebP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/) [download](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/download) or something else?

Comment: Perhaps you could load a [webp polyfill](https://www.google.com/search?q=webp+polyfill) into each page?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance @JohnHatton, but sadly, that didn't work. I tried both [WebPJS](https://webpjs.appspot.com/) and [WebP-Hero](https://github.com/chase-moskal/webp-hero). I feel it may be an issue with the browser version as you mentioned above.